# Error building Docker image in Windows 7

Tags: docker, dockerfile

New to docker and I'm using Windows 7 SP1. It looks like docker is running fine in my machine as I have tried running hello-world by command `docker run hello-world` as instructed in the tutorial and got expected result. Now all I'm trying to do is create a docker image for a .net core console app. My app built and ran. but while building docker image by command `docker build -t myapp .` I get the below error

> error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&c
>   puquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=
>   duke&target=&ulimits=null: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on
>   Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

Below my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime-nanoserver

WORKDIR /DotNetConsole
COPY /bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish/ .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DotNetConsole.dll"]
```

Comment: Are you using the same terminal where you ran the docker run hello-world?

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes the same terminal

Comment: Attache a screenshot of the error and terminal?

Comment: @Riki did you solve the problem? I have the same issue and wondering if you could share us the solution you found to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I could get around this problem by starting the "Docker QuickStart Terminal" installed with the docker tools, and running the commands for building the docker images from there.

If I used GIT BASH instead of the Docker QuickStart Terminal to execute the commands, I would get this kind of error. So it seems that if the commands are not executed from the Docker terminal itself, these errors show up.